# Crear archivos en ensamblador

Tags: ensamblador

estoy trabajando en lenguaje ensamblador para el microprocesador 8086, utilizo el emu8086, el problema que tengo es que debo crear un archivo, hasta este momento todo bien con la instrucción 3ch, el problema surge cuando **el archivo debo nombrarlo mediante una entrada por teclado**, no logro unir la ruta con el nombre que ingreso para el archivo.

```
.data
ruta db "c:\archivos\","$",00h ;especificar directorio del archivo
nombre db  13 dup('$')
code.
create:
;proceso de crear


nombres:
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    mov nombre[si],al
    inc si
    cmp al,0dh
    ja nombres
    jb nombres

mov ruta[1],ax

mov ah,3ch ;instrucción para crear el archivo.
mov cx,0
mov dx,offset ruta ;crea el archivo con el nombre .txt indicado indicado en la parte .data
int 21h
```

esto es lo que he intentado pero no resulta, realmente no tengo mucha idea, agradecería su apoyo